# d3.js, log scale : add more ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my scale :

```
var y = d3.scale.log()
    .domain( [ 13, 21 ] )
    .range( [ 300, 0 ] );
```

And my axis :

```
var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale( y )
    .orient( 'right' )
    .tickSize( -width )
    .tickFormat( function ( v ) {
        if ( v > 999 ) return numeral( v ).format( '0.0a' );
        else return v;
    } )
    .ticks( 10 );
```

I hoped I could have a few ticks, but I only get one tick (21).

When I add `nice()` to the scale definition, I have the ticks I want; but my scale starts to 10 and goes to 100 ; and that is not good at all.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can use `.tickValues()` to specify the tick values explicitly.

Comment: Well, I wrote 13 and 21, but this is not fixed values, it could be 47 to 48 or 1 to 1 million

Comment: This is your only other option if you don't want to use `.nice()`.

Comment: When you change your y scale, you will need to re-apply it to the axis (and re-apply the axis to the chart), so you can update your .tickValues() dynamically at that time based on the new y scale domain.